# Why is there no subtracting effect for sculpting brush?

Tags: sculpting

I would like a small help with an issue that occurs while I try to enter Sculpt mode.
I don't use Dyntopo (don't want to add more faces to my mesh that I have nor to break and add new. I am working with what I have and just wish to "reorganise" them a little bit).
Sadly, I can only add to my mesh, but I can't use subtracting brush effect. The <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> doesn't work (opposite to what I am doing) and I can't even find the add/subtract option in my tool panel. What am I missing here? Could someone advice me what to do so that I don't use always <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> and do it over until I reach my desired form?

I am new to sculpting, I have watched some tutorials but I just can't find the add/subtract nowhere in "normal"(?) sculpting mode (again, not in dyntopo!).

Thank you in advance.

EDIT: found my problem, it looks like that the F smooth doesn't have an add/subtract option. I just want to smooth a little bit out and then work around that. Sorry for the waste of space.

Comment: While using another brush, hold 'shift' to smooth

Answer (score 1):

Found my problem, it looks like that the "F smooth" doesn't have an add/subtract option. I just want to smooth a little bit out and then work around that. Sorry for the waste of space. Perhaps the option "add/subtract" might be welcome for this option also.

Comment: You can really spped up workflow by holding Shift to use Smooth brush. Not sure what the reason for it to have Subtract effect; to deepen strokes, use Deepen brush, to flatten - use flattening brushes. Smooth uses smoothing in general so there might not be any opposite effect to it.

Comment: You aren't wasting space. The point of SE is that someone else might have had this question as well. If you think your answer is the best answer, you can accept it BTW.